# Using `ipywidgets.iteract`, is it possible to locate the output beside the widgets and not below them?

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

When using the [`ipywidgets.interact`](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html) function in Jupyter notebooks, the output is always below the widgets. Is it possible to show it besides the widgets?
In other words, instead of this:
[image: before: the output is below the widget]

(taken from [this example](https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets/blob/master/docs/source/examples/Image%20Browser.ipynb)),

I would like to see something like this:

[image: after: the output is on the right of the widget]

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If not let me know so I can fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the `interactive` function along with `HBox` and or `VBox`

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301231/python-resetting-a-matplotlib-from-an-ipywidget-button/44374923#44374923) as an example with the following lines for the desired effect:

```
hb = widgets.VBox([my_plts.children[0],my_plts.children[1]])

widgets.HBox([my_plts.children[2], hb])
```

However the plot does not appear at first you have to start moving the sliders for it to render. At least that's been my experience. I'm sure there is a way to fix it but I'm to lazy to investigate. Hope that helps!